# Offline dictionary database for android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, dictionary

I looked, but could not find. Sorry for my stupidity, but nonetheless, where can I find an offline English dictionary (word, definition, synonyms, etc.) in a form of a sqlite database? Or is there something else like that? Please leave a suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.mso.anu.edu.au/~ralph/OPTED/

This is what I've always used when I've needed a dictionary. It has definitions and part of speech, but not synonyms.

It's in plain text with some html formatting, however with a simple script I'm sure you could parse it into a SQL database. It will probably end up being fairly large though.

Comment: Thanks man, you made my day :) Also, do you know by any chance any lighter weight ones? XD